# Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption. Problem in decryption

Tags: java, spring-boot, aes

I am facing an error while decryption of 1 of the parameters named as CardHolderName().
Please find the error snippet below:

```
Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at com.example.encryptdecrypt.utils.AES.decrypt(AES.java:79)
    at com.example.encryptdecrypt.service.EncryptionServiceimpl.decrypt(EncryptionServiceimpl.java:36)
    at com.example.encryptdecrypt.EncryptionController.EncryptionController.userDecryptusingKey(EncryptionController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Please find my attached code snippet for the same.

```java
@PostMapping("/userdecryptusingKey")
public User userDecryptusingKey(@RequestBody Map<String,String> secretKeybody) {
    String secretKey = secretKeybody.get("secretKey");
    User user1 = encryptionService.getUserByKey(secretKey);
    System.out.println(user1.getCardHolderName());
    user1.setCardHolderName(encryptionService.decrypt(user1.getCardHolderName(),secretKey));
    user1.setCvv(encryptionService.decrypt(user1.getCvv().toString(),secretKey));
    
    return user1;
}
```

This is the function for generating the Key

```java
private void setKey() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(256);
        secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```java
public static SecretKey convertStringToSecretKey(String encodedKey) {
    //System.out.println("encoded key"+ encodedKey);
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey,"AES");
    return originalKey;
}
```

```java
public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt,String key){
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey1 = convertStringToSecretKey(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey1);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } catch ( InvalidKeyException |IllegalBlockSizeException |NoSuchAlgorithmException| NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("error decr" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am able to fetch the CVV value without any problem, but cardHolderName() is coming as null.

I have tried numerous changes for doFinal() and update() still not working.

Comment: `decrypt` returns `null` when there is an exception, is there any?

Comment: Yes, decrypt for cardHolderName() is returning null.  The response which i am getting is: 
{
    "id": 7,
    "cardHolderName": null,
    "cvv": "564",
    "key": "3Sq2X3BC2/TseicePrAsqwsyvbLP1cQ3TT8O85StPB8="
}